# How to get attribute values from xml data stored as a string?

Tags: php, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a android manifest file that is xml. Suppose its data is stored in a string variable `$xmldata` as below:
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versioncode="13507140" android:versionname="1.35.7" package="com.google.android.apps.youtube.music" platformbuildversioncode="23" platformbuildversionname="6.0-2166767">
    <uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="16" android:targetsdkversion="23">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait">
    <compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screensize="200" android:screendensity="160">
        <screen android:screensize="200" android:screendensity="240">
        <screen android:screensize="200" android:screendensity="320">
        <screen android:screensize="400" android:screendensity="420">
        <screen android:screensize="400" android:screendensity="480">
        <screen android:screensize="400" android:screendensity="560">
        <screen android:screensize="400" android:screendensity="640">
    </screen></screen></screen></screen></screen></screen></screen></compatible-screens>
   </uses-feature></uses-permission></uses-sdk></manifest>`

How to get all `android:screendensity` values in array?
This is android manifest file so xml structure differs from normal xml file.
View Full XML [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7qWRxnVB5E1MmVuOHkyZDUta1E/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your xml is wrong. 
The "screen" tag should be closed like this:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="200" android:screenDensity="160"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="200" android:screenDensity="240"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="200" android:screenDensity="320"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="400" android:screenDensity="420"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="400" android:screenDensity="480"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="400" android:screenDensity="560"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="400" android:screenDensity="640"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

Then if you use PHP, use parser library as commented by @ThW. 
Or I recommend you to use regular expression like this:

```
preg_match_all("/screenDensity=\"(\d+)\"/", $xmldata, $result);

// $result[1]; is array of screenDensitys
```

Comment: XML structure looks invalid but this is what android apk files contain.

Comment: Wow I wasn't aware of that. But the reguler expretion in my answer will work anyway.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. full xml contains duplicate values also, so I used array_unique() also :)